# Trouble iterating over both worksheets and columns in VBA Excel

Tags: vba, excel, nested-loops

I currently have data in a certain column in 78 worksheets in the same worksheet that I would like to copy into another sheet in my Workbook titled "Sheet 2". Essentially 
I am taking the numbers in the Range B3:B195 in each of the 78 worksheets and then pasting it into a column in "Sheet 2" so that when the sub is finished, Sheet 2 should have 78 columns each with the data from one of the worksheets. However, when I run the macro nothing happens in the worksheet and when I step into the macro it seems as if the loops are just skipped.

```
Sub TransferData()
Dim numSheets As Long
Dim columnsAcross As Long
Dim lengthOfColumn As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim y As String

For numSheets = 2 To numSheets = 79
    columnCounter = 1
        For lengthOfColumn = 1 To lengthOfColumn = 192
            y = "B" & (columnCounter + 3)
            Worksheets("Sheet 2").Range(Cells(lengthOfColumn, numSheets), Cells(lengthOfColumn, numSheets)) = Worksheets(numSheets).Range(y)
            columnCounter = columnCounter + 1
        Next lengthOfColumn
Next numSheets

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    For i = 2 To 79
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range( _
                                     Split(Cells(, i - 1).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                     "2:" & _
                                     Split(Cells(, i - 1).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                     "195" _
                                     ).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("B2:B195").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

**FOLLOWUP (From Comments)**

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

    For i = 2 To 79
        '~~> Get Values from A1
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range( _
                                     Split(Cells(, i - 1).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                     "1" _
                                     ).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("A1").Value

        '~~> Get the column Values
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range( _
                                     Split(Cells(, i - 1).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                     "2:" & _
                                     Split(Cells(, i - 1).Address, "$")(1) & _
                                     "195" _
                                     ).Value = _
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("B2:B195").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: May I see your Excel file?

Comment: Never mind it worked but would it be possible for you to show me how to do one more thing? I need to add the contents of cell A1 in each sheet to the top of each column in the new sheet, the one with 78 columns.

Comment: @user10055: Updated the post. Hope that is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub TransferData()
Dim numSheets As Long
Dim columnCounter As Long
Dim wb As Workbook

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    columnCounter = 1
    For numSheets = 2 To numSheets = 79

        wb.Worksheets(numSheets).Range("B3:B195").Copy _
            wb.Worksheets("Sheet 2").Cells(1, columnCounter)

        columnCounter = columnCounter + 1

    Next numSheets

End Sub
```

Comment: + 1 Damn! Damn! Damn! LOL

Comment: The code didn't work at all. Should I post a link to the workbook?

Comment: No, your macro didn't do anything and didn't give an error but the answer by Siddharth Rout worked. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have Sheet 2 at the back (the last sheet)

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim i As Long

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet 2")

    For i = 1 To 78
        ws.Range("A1:A193").Offset(0, i - 1) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(i).Range("B3:B195").Value
    Next i
End Sub
```